# Is it customary to say いらっしゃいませ in a corporate setting?

Tags: keigo, business-japanese

Related: [Is it appropriate to use irasshaimase when welcoming someone to a private office?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44805/is-it-appropriate-to-use-irasshaimase-when-welcoming-someone-to-a-private-office/44808#44808)

In the related question, the target is "someone", which brings me to the conclusion that OP there means "if anyone other than people working in the same office arrives, should いらっしゃいませ be used?".

For example, when clients of a software engineering firm you're working for visit your office, is it customary to say いらっしゃいませ since they are customers, or is いらっしゃいませ usually just said in a service-oriented environment (such as restaurants, hotels, and shops)?

Context: We have a Japanese HR Officer who happened to be in the same room as us when the clients arrived and she greeted with いらっしゃいませ, which perplexed me a bit because I thought it was only used for restaurants and whatnot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is いらっしゃいませ usually just said in a service-oriented environment (such as
>   restaurants, hotels, and shops)?

Yes, it is.

I think it's not wrong in your office but a little weird.

"お待ちしておりました。(Omachisiteorimasita)" may be best for this situation.
It means like "We(I) have been waiting for you."

Comment: btw when I was looking forward a new job in Japan, every interviewer said "お待ちしておりました。(Omachisiteorimasita)"  to me.

Comment: I'd always thought the waiting was done by the listener, so "お待ちしておりました" meant "you have done us the courtesy of waiting".

Comment: @muru お待ちしておりました is 謙譲語; it would be a faux pas if it referred to the listener.

Answer (score 2):

When someone comes to your place or office, you can say ようこそいらっしゃいました which is basically "Welcome, nice to see you!" You can use this in your office and in your home as well.

Comment: Also is polite to say "どうぞお上がりください｡" or "どうぞお入りください｡"  this is basically "Please come in."

Comment: Another alternative is "お越しいただきありがとうございます" it means "thank you for coming"

Comment: The order of greetings like: 1. お待ちしておりました。 2.　お越しいただきありがとうございました。 or ようこそいらっしゃいました。 34. どうぞお上がりください。 or　どうぞお入りください。